# How to retrieve data from DBHelper by HashMap in Multicolumn ListView

Tags: android, hashmap

I want to View my record in Multicolumn ListView From DBHelper Class by HashMap. that will show my data in multicolumn and also all rows are clickable. i have some difficulty. my  code is here

DBHelper.java

```
 public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getdata(){
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> maplist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "select * from tbexpenses";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                for(int i=0; i<c.getColumnCount();i++){
                    map.put(c.getColumnName(i), c.getString(i));
                }
                }while (c.moveToNext());
            }db.close();
            return maplist;
    }
```

ListView.java

```
 package com.multiplecolumnlist;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import static com.multiplecolumnlist.Constants.FIRST_COLUMN;
 import static com.multiplecolumnlist.Constants.FOURTH_COLUMN;
 import static com.multiplecolumnlist.Constants.SECOND_COLUMN;
 import static com.multiplecolumnlist.Constants.THIRD_COLUMN; 

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    ?????????????????????????????????????????????

    ListViewAdapters adapter=new ListViewAdapters(this, list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
    {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id)
          {
            int pos=position+1;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Integer.toString(pos)+" Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
          }

    });

}
```

ListViewAdapter.java

```
public class ListViewAdapters extends BaseAdapter{

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
Activity activity;
TextView txtFirst;
TextView txtSecond;
TextView txtThird;
TextView txtFourth;
public ListViewAdapters(Activity activity,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list){
    super();
    this.activity=activity;
    this.list=list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    LayoutInflater inflater=activity.getLayoutInflater();

    if(convertView == null){

        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.column_row, null);

        txtFirst=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        txtSecond=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gender);
        txtThird=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.age);
        txtFourth=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);

    }

    HashMap<String, String> map=list.get(position);
    txtFirst.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
    txtSecond.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
    txtThird.setText(map.get(THIRD_COLUMN));
    txtFourth.setText(map.get(FOURTH_COLUMN));

    return convertView;
}

}
```

Constant.java

```
public class Constants {

public static final String FIRST_COLUMN="First";
public static final String SECOND_COLUMN="Second";
public static final String THIRD_COLUMN="Third";
public static final String FOURTH_COLUMN="Fourth";
}
```

Comment: then what is your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this code with question mark

```
list.clear();
DBHelper helper = new DBHelper();
list = helper.getdata();
```

**EDIT 1:Error in `getdata()` method**

Also check your `getdata()` function

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getdata(){
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> maplist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "select * from tbexpenses";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if(c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            // you are creating map here but not adding this map to list
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for(int i=0; i<c.getColumnCount();i++) {
                map.put(c.getColumnName(i), c.getString(i));
            }
            // so do add it here
            maplist.add(map);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return maplist;
}
```

Then it'll run fine.

Comment: there are showing empty list with complete row from dbhelper

Comment: What u mean by that? Are you inserting any value in you table "tbexpenses"?

Comment: No, i want to get value in hashmap column  from db

Comment: Need more information,not clear with your question.It will be very helpfull