# How to settext with Map<String, Object>?

Tags: java, android, listview, kumulos

ORIGINAL POST:

How do you set a textview with an object? I am pulling data from a webservice database and setting it to an object. I am then attempting to set the data in the object to a textview.

What I need help with:

1) setting a textview with Map String, Object

Previous post regarding webservice database: [Populating a ListView with Kumulos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36879733/populating-a-listview-with-kumulos/36916164?noredirect=1#comment61427454_36916164)

UPDATING CODE:

The object:

```
static class Person{

    public long personID;
    public String lastName;
    public String middleName;
    public String firstName;
    public String dateOfBirth;
    public String personAddress;
    public int phoneNumber;
    public int driversLicense;
    public int socialSecurity;
    public String personRace;
    public String personSex;
    public String personAge;

    public static Person createFromGenericMap(Map<String, Object> object) {

        Person p = new Person();

        p.personID = Long.valueOf(object.get("personID").toString());
        p.lastName = (String) object.get("lastName");
        p.middleName = (String) object.get("middleName");
        p.firstName = (String) object.get("firstName");
        p.dateOfBirth = (String) object.get("dob");
        p.personAddress = (String) object.get("address");
        p.phoneNumber = Integer.valueOf(object.get("phone").toString());
        p.driversLicense = Integer.valueOf(object.get("dl").toString());
        p.socialSecurity = Integer.valueOf(object.get("ss").toString());
        p.personRace = (String) object.get("race");
        p.personSex = (String) object.get("sex");
        p.personAge = (String) object.get("age");

        return p;
    }
}
```

My adapter:

```
static class PersonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Person> people;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public PersonAdapter(Context context, List<Person> people){
        this.people = people;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return people.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return people.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        Person p = people.get(position);
        return p.personID;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.personlist_row, null);

            TextView dl = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvdl);
            TextView last = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvLastName);
            TextView first = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvFirstName);
            TextView middle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvMiddleName);
            TextView ss = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSS);

            Person mperson = people.get(position);

            dl.setText(mperson.driversLicense);
            last.setText(mperson.lastName);
            first.setText(mperson.firstName);
            middle.setText(mperson.middleName);
            ss.setText(mperson.socialSecurity);   
        }
```

ERROR:

> 05-09 23:34:02.000 2418-2418/com.f0xcr4f7.intelwatch E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.f0xcr4f7.intelwatch, PID: 2418
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID
>   '#0x2d9f9219 at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:299) at
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4132) at
>   com.f0xcr4f7.intelwatch.PersonSearchPop$PersonAdapter.getView(PersonSearchPop.java:112)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me this part looks quite weird.

```
   --------------------------------------------------------------------
        Map<String, Object> mperson = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        mperson = people.get(position);

        dl.setText(mperson.getString("dl"));
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You define mperson as HashMap, but you recieve a Person object from people, which is List of Person.
So what I would do

```
 Person mperson = people.get(position);
 d1.setText(mPerson.driverLicense + "");
```

Comment: Getting an error on the Person mperson = people.get(position);? Its saying that the variable is already defined in the scope. Only other place that is similar is the Person p = people.get(position); but why would that matter?

Comment: So is it worked with p = people.get(position)? If so it means that you have already declared mPerson, if you want to reuse mPerson and if it is of right type, remove type declaration `mPerson = people.get(position);`

Comment: Ok, I am now able to come back to this and see if it works now but it does not. Ill update the original post.

Comment: Check if your textViews are not null and try to convert your int fields like phoneNumber to String while setting text for the textView.

Comment: dl.setText(Integer.toString(mperson.driversLicense)); works but the IDE is suggesting that I use String.format instead?

Comment: you can just write dl.setText(mperson.driversLicense + ""); or String.valueOf();  or leave your way if it works.